# Need to Create an input element that takes only letters from a-z, A-Z and space

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, domdocument

> Create an input element on the page with a placeholder” enter your name” and an
> H2 heading on the page inside HTML.
> The purpose of this input element is to enter a user’s name so it should only input.
> letters from a-z, A-Z and space (all other characters should not be detected).
> Whenever the user inputs their name, their input should be dynamically visible inside the heading.
> [Please note that no other character apart from the allowed characters should be visible in the heading]

HTML CODE Inside body

```
<h2></h2>
    <input placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

JavaScript Code

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");

input.addEventListener("input",function(){
    console.log(input.value);
    h2.innerText=input.value;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: You need to add your attempt to check the characters that are entered. We're not going to do it for you, the point of the exercise is for you to figure it out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeinput` event and test whether `Event::data` matches your allowed characters. If not, call `Event::preventDefault()` to cancel the changing of the input:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("beforeinput", e => /^[A-Za-z ]+$/.test(e.data) || e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inpt = document.querySelector("input");
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");

inpt.addEventListener("input",function(){
    let username = inpt.value;
h2.innerText = username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');
})
```

```html
<h2>....</h2>
 <br>
 <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).